# Use tf.metrics in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, wrapper, keras-2

I'm especially interested in [`specificity_at_sensitivity`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/specificity_at_sensitivity). Looking through [the Keras docs](https://keras.io/metrics):

```
from keras import metrics

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=[metrics.mae, metrics.categorical_accuracy])
```

But it looks like the `metrics` list must have functions of arity 2, accepting `(y_true, y_pred)` and returning a single tensor value.

---

EDIT: Currently here is how I do things:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

predictions = model.predict(x_test)
y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=-1)
predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)
c = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
print('Confusion matrix:\n', c)
print('sensitivity', c[0, 0] / (c[0, 1] + c[0, 0]))
print('specificity', c[1, 1] / (c[1, 1] + c[1, 0]))
```

The disadvantage of this approach, is I only get the output I care about when training has finished. Would prefer to get metrics every 10 epochs or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a related issue on [github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6050), and it seems that `tf.metrics` are still not supported by Keras models. However, in case you are very interested in using [tf.metrics.specificity_at_sensitivity](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/specificity_at_sensitivity), I would suggest the following workaround (inspired by [BogdanRuzh's](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6050#issuecomment-329996505) solution):

```
def specificity_at_sensitivity(sensitivity, **kwargs):
    def metric(labels, predictions):
        # any tensorflow metric
        value, update_op = tf.metrics.specificity_at_sensitivity(labels, predictions, sensitivity, **kwargs)

        # find all variables created for this metric
        metric_vars = [i for i in tf.local_variables() if 'specificity_at_sensitivity' in i.name.split('/')[2]]

        # Add metric variables to GLOBAL_VARIABLES collection.
        # They will be initialized for new session.
        for v in metric_vars:
            tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, v)

        # force to update metric values
        with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
            value = tf.identity(value)
            return value
    return metric


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=[metrics.mae,
                       metrics.categorical_accuracy,
                       specificity_at_sensitivity(0.5)])
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You can use [model.evaluate](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate) to retrieve the metrics after training.

Comment: Thanks, that's working. I'm getting output throughout. It's useful, so I'll upvote. But I've also edited my original question.

Comment: , but how do I get sensitivity and specificity every 10 epochs?

Comment: I'm unsure how you want it exactly, but you could probably define a custom callback to do that: https://keras.io/callbacks/#create-a-callback.

Comment: Thanks. I've marked your answer as correct, and posted a different question on the edited topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50568409

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a strict limit to only two incoming arguments, in metrics.py the function is just three incoming arguments, but k selects the default value of 5.

```
def sparse_top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=5):
    return K.mean(K.in_top_k(y_pred, K.cast(K.max(y_true, axis=-1), 'int32'), k), axis=-1)
```