# Report Keras model evaluation metrics every 10 epochs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, performance-testing, keras-2

I'd like to know the specificity and sensitivity of my model. Currently, I'm evaluating the model after all epochs are finished:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

predictions = model.predict(x_test)
y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=-1)
predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)
c = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
print('Confusion matrix:\n', c)
print('sensitivity', c[0, 0] / (c[0, 1] + c[0, 0]))
print('specificity', c[1, 1] / (c[1, 1] + c[1, 0]))
```

The disadvantage of this approach, is I only get the output I care about when training has finished. Would prefer to get metrics every 10 epochs or so.

BTW: Tried with the [`metrics=[]` here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50539213). Possibly a [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#create-a-callback) is the way to go?

Comment: A custom callback is indeed a good way of having custom operations done during training, look towards implementing one and make sure to add it to the model training. As with every class, you can pass your test set to the callback, in order to use it when checking your metrics mid-training

Answer (score 15):

A custom [Callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#create-a-callback) would be a nice solution giving you enough control over the training procedure. Something along the lines of:

```
class SensitivitySpecificityCallback(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch % 10 == 1:
            x_test = self.validation_data[0]
            y_test = self.validation_data[1]
            # x_test, y_test = self.validation_data
            predictions = self.model.predict(x_test)
            y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=-1)
            predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)
            c = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)

            print('Confusion matrix:\n', c)
            print('sensitivity', c[0, 0] / (c[0, 1] + c[0, 0]))
            print('specificity', c[1, 1] / (c[1, 1] + c[1, 0]))
```

where `epoch` is the epoch number and `logs` contain the usual metrics + loss the model trains.

Then run with:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          shuffle='batch',
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[SensitivitySpecificityCallback()])
```

NOTE: if you don't like how your model is training based on your metrics you can cut the training short with:

```
self.model.stop_training = True
```

which will stop the training for you.

Comment: Thanks, that set me on the right direction. Edited your code to make it actually work.

Comment: We used a similar approach with a custom callback to report loss on the validation dataset many times during the epoch. We used it for a while until I found that `model.validate` resets all metrics so each time we do `model.validate` while the epoch is in progress, we lose all training metrics, overwriting them with validation metrics. It's a very surprising side effect of `model.validate`, and IMO it's a bad design on the`model.validate` part. I know your code above doesn't have this problem but I'm writing this as a warning against using `model.validate` in callbacks.